# Kivy Popup displays at the end of cycle

Tags: python, kivy, popup, kivy-language

I have a script that processes data - for instance 5 csv files. After the script loads a csv, it will ask the user to provide additional data input for the specific csv with the Popup window, therefore in this case, there would be 5 Popup windows.

The problem is that the script ignores the calling of the Popup windows in the desired part of the code and it displays them at the very end of the code. It displays it in reverse order, however that is, because the newest window is atop of the old ones.

Below is a code, that represents my problem. In the commented part, there is my first try, in which the Popup is simply called in the main thread. Similar problem has been asked already, so then I have modified the code with threading, however it did not solve the issue, because the problem, that has been asked, was with progress bar, which should run the code togather with the Popup I assume.

So my question is: Is there a way to **freeze** the code when the Popup is called and after user give a variable in the Popup **then** proceed with the code with the variable from the user.

**test.kv :**

```
<FirstWindow>
    name: "second"

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.91,0.91,0.91,1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            size_hint_x: 1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing:10
            Button:
                font_size: 30
                text: "Press to get Popup"
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.Main_code()
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            size_hint_x: 1

<MyPopup>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Test'
    BoxLayout:
        text_input: text_input
        text_input2: text_input2
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: Datum
            font_size: 25
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Test line one"
            TextInput:
                id: text_input
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Test line two"
            TextInput:
                id: text_input2
        Button:
            text: 'Confirm'
            on_press: root.dismiss()
```

**.py file:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import threading

Window.size = (1200, 700)

class FirstWindow(Screen):
    popup_text = StringProperty()
    popup_text2 = StringProperty()

    def poptest (self,date):
        p = MyPopup(date)
        p.content.text_input.bind(text=self.setter('popup_text'))
        p.content.text_input2.bind(text=self.setter('popup_text2'))
        p.open()

    def Main_code(self):
        year = " .1.2020 0:00"
        con = 1
        while con<5:
            date = str(con) + year

            mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.poptest(date))
            mythread.start()

            # p = MyPopup(date)
            # p.content.text_input.bind(text=self.setter('popup_text'))
            # p.content.text_input2.bind(text=self.setter('popup_text2'))
            # p.open()

            print(self.popup_text)
            print(self.popup_text2)
            print("Cycle " + str(con) + " finished")
            con +=1

class MyPopup(Popup):
    date = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, date, **kwargs):
        super(MyPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.Datum.text = "Date since: " + str(date)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

with open("test.kv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    Builder.load_string(f.read())

window = WindowManager()
screens = [FirstWindow(name="second")]
for screen in screens:
    window.add_widget(screen)
window.current = "second"

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [locks](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#lock-objects) to force a thread to wait for another thread. Here is a modified version of your code that uses a lock:

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import threading

Window.size = (1200, 700)

class FirstWindow(Screen):
    popup_text = StringProperty()
    popup_text2 = StringProperty()

    def poptest (self, p, dt):
        # the instance of MyPopup is passed as an arg
        p.content.text_input.bind(text=self.setter('popup_text'))
        p.content.text_input2.bind(text=self.setter('popup_text2'))
        p.open()

    def Main_code(self):
        # run the loop in another thread (not the main thread)
        mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.old_main_code, daemon=True)
        mythread.start()


    def old_main_code(self):
        # create a lock to be used in keeping this thread and the MyPopups sychronized
        lock = threading.Lock()
        lock.acquire()

        year = " .1.2020 0:00"
        con = 1
        while con<5:
            date = str(con) + year

            lock.release()  # release the lock so that the MyPopup can acquire it
            pop = MyPopup(lock, date)  # create Popup here to be sure it acquires lock
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.poptest, pop))  # run poptest on main thread
            lock.acquire()  # wait for the Popup to release the lock

            print(self.popup_text)
            print(self.popup_text2)
            print("Cycle " + str(con) + " finished")
            con +=1

class MyPopup(Popup):
    date = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, lock, date, **kwargs):
        lock.acquire()  # acquire the lock to force the other thread to wait
        super(MyPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.Datum.text = "Date since: " + str(date)
        self.lock = lock

    def myDismiss(self):
        self.dismiss()
        self.lock.release()  # release the lock to allow while loop to continue

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


with open("test.kv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    Builder.load_string(f.read())

window = WindowManager()
screens = [FirstWindow(name="second")]
for screen in screens:
    window.add_widget(screen)
window.current = "second"

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

The only change to the `kv` file is to set the `Confirm` button to call `root.myDismiss()`:

```
    Button:
        text: 'Confirm'
        on_press: root.myDismiss()
```